# How to set/get values in <p> tag with reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code in my js file

```
<p ref={(c) => (this.text = c)} className="form-control-static" />
```

How can I set and get values from the p?

calling this.text.value does not work at all.

Comment: If you want to get/set the value I think its better to use `state` for that.

Comment: What do you mean by "values"?

Comment: @fl0cke, <p>value</p>

Comment: @ken4z, thanks. that worked and its better than setting innerHTML as suggested by Juan. I will choose your answer if you ever submit it as an answer instead of a comment. =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for `this.textContent`

Answer (score 2):

`this.text` will point to the `p` HTML element, it does not have a text property, it does have a `innerHTML` property or `textContent` property

Comment: but isnt setting the innerHTML unsafe?

Comment: I'm not suggesting you set it, I'm just telling you that there is no `text` property